# Adding custom attribute to a field through mvc ValidationAttribute extension

Tags: model-view-controller, validation, tags, required, wai-aria

So I have an issue around a custom attribute I want to add to all required fields. Now instead of extending all my helper classes to include this attribute to the input if required, I wondered if I could just save a lot of time and add it in the custom required attribute itself.

Something like this:

model:

[MyCustomRequiredValidator]<--I want to add it in the validationAttribute extension
public int? myField

I obviously can't just add it via the ModelClientValidationRule because it prefixes the attribute with data-val- which is no good but I can't seem to get access to the attributes themselves.  I've tried using metadata.AdditionValue.add but no joy there.

The attribute I want to add is aria-required="true" for screen reader support.

Is this possible?

Any advice would be great because I've hit a wall.

thanks for looking.

Answer (score 1):

OK so for what it's worth I found a solution.  I added a tag to the meta data through all the required validators on creation of the metadata (I had to also inherit the IMetadataAware interface on the class declaration):

```
public void OnMetadataCreated(ModelMetadata metadata) {
    metadata.AdditionalValues.Add("AriaRequired", "true");
}
```

I then extended all the input field helpers to check for this value and add a custom attribute to the input by checking the existence of the above attribute, in this case AriaRequired.

```
if (htmlAttributes == null) htmlAttributes = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    if (!htmlAttributes.ContainsKey("aria-required"))
    {
        ModelMetadata metaData = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData);
        htmlAttributes.Add("aria-required", metaData.IsAriaRequiredValue());
    }
}
```

Hope this helps people :-)